# # Deprecate: Copied verbatim from Rails source, remove once we move to Rails 4 only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails, while i was looking inside the devise i found this "# Deprecate: Copied verbatim from Rails source, remove once we move to Rails 4 only." written in  devise / lib / devise / token_generator.rb.
My question is what does this line "# Deprecate: Copied verbatim from Rails source, remove once we move to Rails 4 only." means....

Comment: I answered your question, but it doesn't really belong in StackOverflow as it is not related to programming. Try http://english.stackexchange.com/ next time. Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: This question belongs to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"verbatim" means "word for word". The code found in that Devise file is exactly the same as the one found in Rails 4's codebase. Since Devise has to support Rails 2 & 3, it has to include that duplicate code.

In the future, when Devise stops supporting Rails 2 & 3, this code may be deprecated/removed in favour of Rails 4's code.